# How can you add a class to a tag with a custom attribute in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can you add a class to a tag with a custom attribute? Most people use ID, but in my case I need to use a custom attribute.

CSS:

```
.correct {
    background-color: lightGREEN;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(".save").on("click", function(){
    $("input[custom='50']").addClass("correct");
}
```

HTML:

```
<button type='button' class='save' value='Save' custom='50' >Save</button>
```

bootply:

http://www.bootply.com/XgCASbBRZR

Comment: after your closing curly brackets you need to close the on command with `);` and as mentioned below it is better to use $(this) if you are manipulating the element you have just clicked.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a parenthesis in your jquery, and are adding the class `correct` to an `input`, so I added the `input` to your html.

```js
$(".save").on("click", function(){
    $("input[custom='50']").addClass("correct");
});
```

```css
.correct {
    background-color: lightGREEN;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type='button' class='save' value='Save' custom='50' >Save</button>
<input custom="50">
```

If you're intending to change the background color of the button, reference the button in your jquery

```js
$(".save").on("click", function(){
    $("button[custom='50']").addClass("correct");
});
```

```css
.correct {
    background-color: lightGREEN;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type='button' class='save' value='Save' custom='50' >Save</button>
```

Comment: This works great and I understand how it work.  Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `this` keyword, which represents a reference to the object that invoked the current function. In our case, the `button` clicked.

```
 $(this).addClass("correct");
```

```js
$(".save").on("click", function(){
    $(this).addClass("correct");
});
```

```css
.correct {
    background-color: lightGREEN;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type='button' class='save' value='Save' custom='50' >Save</button>
```

If you want to select a `DOM` element by custom attribute you have to use this:

```
$('button[custom="50"]').addClass("correct");
```